# External keyboard not recognized

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, keyboard

I plugged my external USB keyboard into my new computer. I watched the driver installation and it supposedly installed the driver, but the Keyboard does not work even after several reboots on my new computer but it works fine on my old one.

Today, I went to Device Manager to uninstall the faulty driver. There was only one option, called "Standard PS/2 Keyboard". I pressed uninstall and did not reboot but only now realized that that was my internal laptop keyboard. I then clicked on "Update Driver". Here too I presses "Restart Later" as otherwise I will get into a big fix.

How do I resolve this?

PS: I have a computer running Windows 7 Ultimate and the keyboard is a "Greentree" keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried different USB port?

Comment: Are you using the MS driver or the manufacturers? I suggest the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, the USB keyboard does not recognized as "Standard PS/2 Keyboard" in the device manager. Rather, i would ask you to check the USB keyboard driver under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers". Download the recent USB keyboard driver from the vendor site and uninstall the USB driver from device manager, and then install the downloaded driver.

Meanwhile, two things that you can check. 1. Change the USB port. Sometimes, a loose connectivity may trouble this. 2. Connect the problematic USB keyboard to another machine and ensure it is working in other machines.

Comment: Apparently the internal keyboard was the PS/2 one. After fiddling around in Device Manger, I found an "Unknown Device", uninstalled its driver, rebooted and it works. Thanks